# Unix : how to tar only N first files of each folder?

Tags: unix, tar

I have a folder containing 2Gb of images, with sub-folders several levels deep.

I'd like to archive only `N` files of each (sub) folder in a tar file. I tried to use `find` then `tail` then `tar` but couldn't manage to get it to work. Here is what I tried (assuming `N = 10`):

```
find . | tail -n 10 | tar -czvf backup.tar.gz
```

… which outputs this error:

```
Cannot stat: File name too long
```

What's wrong here? thinking of it - even if it works I think it will tar only the first 10 files of all folders, not the first 10 files of each folder.

How can I get the first `N` files of each folder?

Comment: You might want to migrate this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: Tar doesn't like long path/filename combinations.

Comment: @mark : done, here is the link : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223748/unix-how-to-tar-only-n-first-files-of-each-folder

Comment: @EdHeal: The OP asked his original question twice: once here, and once [over at unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223748/unix-how-to-tar-only-n-first-files-of-each-folder). In a [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223748/unix-how-to-tar-only-n-first-files-of-each-folder#comment380916_223748) on his Unix.SE question, he explains why he wants to do this.

Comment: @unforgettableid - Please check the time of my comment Aug 16th, 10:55 compared with when the question you linked to was the following day

Answer (score 1):

A proposal with some quirks: order is only determined by the order out of `find`, so "first" isn't well-defined.

```
find . -type f |
awk -v N=10 -F / 'match($0, /.*\//, m) && a[m[0]]++ < N' |
xargs -r -d '\n' tar -rvf /tmp/backup.tar

gzip /tmp/backup.tar
```

Comments:

1. use `find . -type f` to ensure that files have a leading directory-name prefix, so the next step can work
2. the `awk` command tracks such leading directory names, and emits full path names until N (10, here) files with the same leading directory have been emitted
3. use `xargs` to invoke `tar` - we're gathering regular file names, and they need to be arguments to that archiving command
4. `xargs` may invoke `tar` more than once, so we'll append (-r option) to a plain archive, then compress it after it's all written

Also, you may not want to write a backup file into the current directory, since you're scanning that - that's why this suggestion writes into /tmp.

Comment: I have an error message : awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,

Comment: What version of awk? MIne is GNU Awk 4.1.0, and its features may make a difference.